How do you import a json file in a typescript project?
I'm unable to import a JSON array of strings into a playwright-lighthouse test.
Here's the actual test:
import { test, expect, chromium } from '@playwright/test';
import { playAudit } from 'playwright-lighthouse';
import { thresholds } from '../../config/thresholds';
import * as URLs from '../../config/urls.json'

URLs.forEach(url => {
  test(`Ligthouse performance test for ${url}`, async () => {
      const browser = await chromium.launch({
          args: ['--remote-debugging-port=9222'],
          headless: false
      });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto(url);
      await playAudit({
          page: page,
          thresholds: thresholds,
          port: 9222,
          reports: {
              formats: {
                  html: true, //defaults to false
              },
              name: `ligthouse-${new Date().toISOString()}`, //defaults to `lighthouse-${new Date().getTime()}`
              directory: `${process.cwd()}/lighthouse`, //defaults to `${process.cwd()}/lighthouse`
          },
      });
      await page.close();
      await browser.close();
  })
});

Error: require() of ES Module /Users/duane.hodges/projects/PERFORMANCE-TESTS/node_modules/lighthouse/core/index.js from /Users/duane.hodges/projects/PERFORMANCE-TESTS/node_modules/playwright-lighthouse/src/task.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/duane.hodges/projects/PERFORMANCE-TESTS/node_modules/playwright-lighthouse/src/task.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.playwright

When I hover over the import error the above error is what I get.
After searching online I saw a post stating this is the resolution. Creating a tsconfig.json file and adding the resolveJsonModule config but this didn't work either:
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}

I've tried the import using the following:
import { URLs } from '../../config/urls.json';

That will at least run the test but then I get the following error:
 PERFORMANCE-TESTS % npx playwright test "home.spec.ts" -g "Ligthouse\s+performance\s+test\s+for\s+(.*?)$"
Error: require() of ES Module /projects/PERFORMANCE-TESTS/node_modules/lighthouse/core/index.js from /projects/PERFORMANCE-TESTS/node_modules/playwright-lighthouse/src/task.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in //projects/PERFORMANCE-TESTS/node_modules/playwright-lighthouse/src/task.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

   at performance/home.spec.ts:4

  2 | import { playAudit } from 'playwright-lighthouse';
  3 | import { thresholds } from '../../config/thresholds';
> 4 | import { URLs } from '../../config/urls.json';


Does this answer your question? Purpose of "resolveJsonModule"?

Note that name: `ligthouse-${new Date().toISOString()} may fail, because toISOString() outputs text with colons (:) which are generally not allowed in file names... might be better to just use name: `ligthouse-${Date.now()} which should be just as unique.

@HereticMonkey wouldn't do that either but it depends, linux (e.g. ext4) has no issues with : in filenames

@zapl Sure, I thought that might be the case, hence "may fail" and "generally not allowed". I usually like to stick to the basics when it comes to file names, but I grew up with 8.3 being the rule (and nothing over a MB or it won't fit on a floppy :)).

That's how I will read Json data in a Playwright test:
Sample Code
const {test, expect} = require('@playwright/test');
import { TestData } from '../test-data.json'

for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(TestData)) {
        
    // Write a test
    test(`Data Driven Testing Using JSON file in playwright ${value}`, async({page}) =>{
        // Go to URL
        await page.goto(process.env.URL);

        // search with keywords
        await page.locator('#url').click();
        await page.locator('#url').fill(value);
        await page.locator('#submit').press('Enter');

        await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    })
}

